# Should we consider an answer which mainly contains great links as a valid answer?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, link-only-answers, not-an-answer

I stumpled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4663977/438154) answer. It attempts to answer the question of [What is REST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663927/what-is-rest-slightly-confused/4663977) by providing two excellent links (a blog-style post and the actual thesis) and an edit explaining that there is no point in explaining REST in a Stack Overflow answer, because there are too many concepts involved. It originally (when I posted this question) read:

> Read [How I explained REST to my wife](http://www.looah.com/source/view/2284), it's a great starting
>   point. Then read Fieldings actual thesis, it's not that advanced (nor
>   is it long! I know you kids in school like it short), can be found
>   [here](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm).
>
> EDIT: I feel it's pointless to try to explain REST, it has so many
>   concepts like scalability, visibility (stateless) etc.. That the
>   reader needs to grasp and the best source for understand those are the
>   actual thesis, it's much more then POST/GET etc.

Based on some previous experiences, I tried removing the links (in my head) to see if the answer would still stand. Without the links, the answer basically reduces to the EDIT which just explains why the answer only has links.

I flagged it as NAA, but the flag got declined.

Should we consider such answers as valid answers or is this a special case?

Note that other answers go into much more detail and still link to those resources.

Comment: Quite conveniently, the link to [How I explained REST to my wife](http://www.looah.com/source/view/2284) is not working right now.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot:  Quite possibly the author of that post, Ryan Tomayko, wishes for that to be removed.  If you follow the alternate link given in the Answer by Mark you will find an apologetic notice to that effect.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem here is with the *question*, not the answer.

Quoting the "too broad" off-topic reason (emphasis mine):

> There are either too many possible answers, or **good answers would be too long for this format**. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

That's exactly it. You can't "explain REST" in a typical-length SO answer, if the user asking the question explicitly said that they **already read a short description and are still not satisfied**:

> I've read through Wikipedia but still cant quite wrap my head around it.

And the answerer agrees:

> I feel it's pointless to try to explain REST.

So, ideally, a *spherical SO user in vacuum* should not even attempt answering, but should flag/vote to close.

Ideally. We still want to help, so we bend the rules a little, leading to this situation.

If one wants to help here, he/she needs to coax more details about what is unclear.

Comment: I love how the question is: 'What is REST?' with the tag Rest, with a tag wiki that explains what rest is.

Answer (score 15):

Let's remove the edit part for now. So it will be just

> Read How I explained REST to my wife, it's a great starting point.
> Then read Fieldings actual thesis, it's not that advanced (nor is it
> long! I know you kids in school like it short), can be found here.
> (I've deliberately avoided using links)

Now, if the link is dead, the reader would be pointed to a 404 page. Then all those

> "it's a great starting point"
>
> "Then read Fieldings actual thesis, it's not that advanced (nor is it
> long! I know you kids in school like it short), can be found here"

become redundant. It's just a way to make your answer ***look like*** it's not link-only answer, when it ***actually is***.

If the link is to be removed as you thought, the post is pretty useless. Comparing the other posts, they have put in a decent effort to explain what REST is at it's basic level.

Even the one with a link to wikipedia is having *some substance*. So it should have been handled as a link-only answer.

But the amount of upvotes and status of being accepted might have influenced the mod who handled it to not delete it. I'd not *delete* it, but would ask the answerer to put in some details lest his post be deleted.

Comment: I don't think this user has been active for a while. Someone would have to extract core information from the links, but potentially ruin the answer as intended by the author.

Comment: In which case it should be converted to a comment then, if the links are to be preserved.

Comment: @Deduplicator as I said, if answerer isn't active, then it can be converted into comment. Otherwise we can ask him to put in some info. If he isn't doing so, the link can be included in second most voted answer, if any so the link is preserved and the answer is deleted too.

Comment: I quite often post links to tutorials/further explanations in my answers. What I do think is necessary though is answering the question on SO. so if you are linking to a page that discusses the answer pull out the necessary parts and make it readable to a SO user to get a basic understanding/answer without clicking on the link.

Answer (score -3):

The general proposition that others can edit Answers, add context for links and thus rescue them from deletion, has many precedents.  For example see [this Meta post by Jeff Atwood from 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135044/why-was-my-answer-a-link-to-the-documentation-deleted/135050#135050):

> Others have edited your answer to include context from the link, so I undeleted it.

I think [this specific case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4663977/438154) is an Answer that could be saved with a modest amount of editing.  The mention of "Fielding's thesis" is probably enough for a determined Google searcher to reconstruct a link that went 404, but the other link has no such hope of reconstruction.  [**NB:** In the course of editing and providing context I discovered the author of "How I explained REST to my wife" (someone other than the author of the SO Answer) has tried to remove it from the web, and I gave up on trying to quote from it.]

If it were left to me, I would preemptively make a generous quote from the "how I explained it to my wife" material and provide a fuller citation for Fielding's thesis.

My threshold is whether the Answer includes enough context for a Reader to judge whether a link is worth pursuing, and I think the Answer meets that test.  Providing more context, to insure against the chance of links going dead, is worthwhile, but deletion for failure to do is much like tossing out the baby with the bathwater.

For reference our Help Center FAQ says this about [using links in Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer):

> Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

In the present context I consider the link to Fielding's dissertation "important", but I've chosen for my edit only to quote the title.  Some discussion occurs in the Comments below about permission to quote and whether adding substantial quoted material is a radical change.  These are reasonable concerns.  Overall I'm in favor of Edits that substantially improve Answers, and would rely on fair use as a copyright defense if that were the complaint.  Still I have made what I consider quite conservative choices in this instance.

The alternative proposed, to make my own Answer in parallel to the Accepted one, is an approach I've used with some similar situations, e.g. [Seeding the Newton iteration for cube root efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463486/seeding-the-newton-iteration-for-cube-root-efficiently/25748892#25748892).  In that case my choice was based partly on my own interest in the Question, but also on the fact the Accepted Answer was a one-liner with only a very summary indication of what a Reader would find if the one link were followed.  Here I felt the OP did a reasonably good job of describing the relation of the link content to the Question, and why it would be better to cite the on-line resources than to attempt a detailed explanation.

Comment: Which parts do you want to quote, and are you sure that's not a *radical change*, which only the author is permitted to do? If you are sure you can make a valid edit rescuing that, feel free to do so. Or just post your own answer with those two links, which makes the link-only-answer redundant as well as NAA.

Comment: I'm comfortable doing that much, esp. as the OP may have become fairly inactive.  Quoting material cited but not quoted by the OP seems a less than radical change.  It turns out the OP is not referring to something he wrote, but a post by a third party titled "How I explained REST to my wife".

Comment: Unless it's really obvious what should have been quoted (and you checked it's permitted, right?), imho it's still a radical edit. Pure motives do not change all that much...

Comment: I don't understand you notion of radical edit, but I've made mine.  If anyone feels I've changed the meaning of the post (which is how I understand *radical edit*), then of course they can rollback my edit.  I think the idea of quoting from Ryan Tomayko's post turns out not to be so helpful (that material is suffuse), but with the additional context there is still a hope that it could be rescued if the current link becomes unavailable.

Comment: Well, the question is up to which point are you helping him present his view properly, and when are you starting to put words into his mouth. I'm most certainly not saying that the post after your edit is worse than before, I'm just not sure whether it's still the OPs answer.

Comment: I took into consideration the Comments that the user Anders left on the Question (one quite lengthy) and on his own Answer and on one by another user.  Note that there was another Answer (posted by Mark) that gives links to the same two resources (one at an alternative URL).