# Under what circumstances is "not an answer" flag not declined, but the answer is not removed?

Tags: support, flags, not-an-answer

I raised a not-an-answer flag on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36304249/1560062). I see that the flag has been marked as helpful:

[image]

But as far as I can tell, it didn't affect this answer. Is there a special case when something like this happens?

Comment: Why did you think that was "not an answer"?

Comment: @CodyGray I can be wrong but a bunch of links is not considered an answer on SO, is it? And I don't think that large enough number of links makes a post more "answerish". But I am not really interested in proving that this question should be removed.

Comment: *Under what circumstances “not an answer” flag is not declined but the answer is not removed?* When the moderator was 50/50 about your initial decision, i.e. not acting negatively either way. It happens to me once in a while with custom flags too.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Thanks. This is pretty much the information I needed. I haven't seen case like this before so it seemed rather strange.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275063/2675154

Comment: [Should we consider an answer which mainly contains great links as a valid answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289644/839601)